# Excel: How to combine cells that contain certain text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a person's name in column A, and the dialog of an online chat in columns B through DN, like this:

```
A           B                  C                   D                

Name        Transcript 1       Transcript 2        Transcript 3        ........

John        Visitor: line 1.   John: line 2.       Visitor: line 3.

Sally       Sally: line 4.     Sally: line 5.      Visitor: line 6.
```

And so on for several thousand rows. My goal is to combine cells containing "Visitor:" in each row into one cell, and in another cell combine the cells containing the Name in column A. So I want to add two new columns to the end like this:

```
DR                        DS

Visitor: line 1.          John: line 2.
Visitor: line 3.

Visitor: line 6.          Sally: line 4.
                          Sally: line 5.
```

I've tried using the `TEXTJOIN` function like so: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Visitor:",B2:DN2)),B2:DN2,""))` and `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2&":",B2:DN2)),B2:DN2,""))`. But I find that this only works for some rows, and returns a value error for others. I can't figure out what the difference is between the rows that work and the rows that don't. I think that the isnumber(find(...)) works fine, but it gets caught up on the if statement, and I'm not sure what the problem is. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try & lije =A1&" "&B1 etc

Comment: There is a limit to the number of characters a cell and TEXTJOIN can hold.  it is 2^15.  Could you be hitting that with some of your rows?

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't think so, since none of the rows contain more than 10,000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Scott Craner in the comments had the right idea, only it wasn't that the rows were too long for the `TEXTJOIN` function, it was that the strings were too long for the `IF` function. Therefore I split the strings using the `LEFT` and `MID` functions like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Visitor:",A2:DN2)),LEFT(A2:DN2,255),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Visitor:",A2:DN2)),MID(A2:DN2,256,255),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Visitor:",A2:DN2)),MID(A2:DN2,511,255),""))
```

and

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2&":",A2:DN2)),LEFT(A2:DN2,255),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2&":",A2:DN2)),MID(A2:DN2,256,255),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2&":",A2:DN2)),MID(A2:DN2,511,255),""))
```

This gives me the exact results I was looking for. It will have to be edited if the string is longer than 765 characters, but for now it suits my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it can be done with excel formulas. But I couldnt do it with built-in commands. I found a code from internet and changed it like below. It solved my problem.

```
Function combinebytext(CriteriaRng As Range, Criteria As Variant, _
    ConcatenateRng As Range, Optional Delimeter As String = " , ") As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim strResult As String
Dim n As Long
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If CriteriaRng.Count <> ConcatenateRng.Count Then
    Combinerows = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To CriteriaRng.Count
                    
    n = InStr(CriteriaRng.Cells(i).Value, Criteria)
    
    If n > 0 Then
        
        strResult = strResult & Delimeter & ConcatenateRng.Cells(i).Value
    End If
Next i
If strResult <> "" Then
    strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(Delimeter) + 1)
End If
combinebytext = strResult
Exit Function
```

ErrHandler:
combinebytext = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJLs9.png)